# Connecting label and point with line/arrow using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is it possible in QGIS to connect labels and points with a line/arrow or something?

In my map it is not clear which label goes with its point. I can't bring it closer because there are many more points to come.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

- First, create labeling fields for X and Y position of your labels in your point table.
- Activate the X and Y positionning in the properties of your layer.

[image: override]

- Create a new "Generator expression" style in your point style, set it to line type, then use the following formulae :

  make_line(make_point($x,$y),make_point( "LABEL_X" , "LABEL_Y" ))

As an enhancement, you can use various fields (or use a plugin to create them all) to control where the align point will be. You could have the use of a rotation field and a vertical and horizontal alignement field.

[image: styling]

The line will move accordingly to your label position, as its arrival point is related to the label positon field.

Answer (score 5):

You could try downloading and installing the **EasyCustomLabeling** plugin from *Plugins* > *Manage and Install Plugins*, this creates a duplicated memory layer of your selected vector layer and contains the same attributes.

(*Note that you will also need to download and install the **Memory Layer Saver** plugin to save the memory layer correctly, this is described in the plugin description*).

Once your label layer is created, you can play with the label placement and style of that layer to try and get what you're looking for:

[image: Plugin]

[image: Label layer settings]

[image: Label layer]

Answer (score 4):

Concerning the method by gisinside: the first step of manually adding x/y attributes for labels  can be omitted; (maybe since QGIS3?) there's an auxiliary variable for label-positionings already present. The variables ar called accordingly: "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx" and "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony".

So in Step Nr. 2 you can use this expression to draw lines:

make_line(make_point($x,$y),make_point( "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx" , "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony"))

Note however, that the auxiliary variables only get a value assigned, if you touch/move the labels with the move-label-tool. Therefore, you only see lines for labels that have been manually moved around.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PostGIS for your spatial data, this post https://sigsemgrilhetas.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/etiquetas-com-guias-em-qgis-e-postgis-labels-leading-lines-with-qgis-and-postgis/ by Alexandre Neto explains how leading lines can be added to the points in your database.

Its a well written tutorial worth reading, it also has a movie in the post that shows how it works.