# QGIS labels moving after saving layer

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am using QGIS 2.18.20 on Win10. I am trying to manually move my labels, and I've followed the protocol from [How can I connect label and point with a line/arrow?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149606).

I've used this protocol in another map and everything went fine, but for some reason, now whenever I try saving my changes my labels move and cluster, and end up looking like this:

[image: map with all labels overlapping]

What is happening?

Comment: Did you label point or multipoint ? If you use manual placement for multipoint you can't have several label for a multipoint. Ain that case workaround is to run a multipoint to single point tool and label the result

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by multipoint... Here I have one label for each point, and I was moving each one around independently. For some reason when I save the layer, they all move and cluster. It's not supposed to be one label for multiple points (although that's what it looks like in the figure). I hope that's clearer.

Comment: By multipoint I mean that one object (ie one line in the attribute table) is represented by several points on the map, in this case the label engine can label all the points ( by checking the label all part option) but if you manually move the label you can only have one...

Comment: Another possibility is a bad choice when setting the field that relate the auxiliary table where the label position are stored, you need to choose a field with unique value. Without more info on how you set up your label and auxiliary table it's hard to troubleshot your issue

Comment: Is there a reason why you still use the old QGIS 2.18? There are newer versions with improved possibilities that make things easier.

Comment: @J.R, I've followed exactly the tutorial I linked above. Here are the summary of my steps:
• First, create labeling fields for X and Y position of your labels in your point data table (e.g. xlabel, ylabel)
• Activate the X and Y positioning in the properties of your layer
• In the Symbology properties, add a new symbol layer
• Set a new "Generator expression" style in your point style
• Set the Geometry type to line type
• Then use the following formulae :
make_line(make_point($x,$y),make_point( "xlabel" , "ylabel" ))
• Toggle editing on and move the labels around

Comment: I'm using this version because a long time ago, I've tried doing something on v3 and the function was still not available for that version, so I went back to v2 and have been using it so far with no issues. The strange thing is that I've done this before and worked nicely. So, I'm not sure why I'm having this problem here. At first I thought it was because I had separated the points in different layers. Then, I thought the issue was because the lat/long system was transformed from a KML file so I had it all changed to decimal degrees. But this happens in all cases :/

Comment: Soooo... I've decided to download and try the newer v.3.16 and the labels are working OK now.